# How to make a list of options from which you can select multiple items and then "submit"

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

A bit of a hard question. I'll first provide some information before asking as it makes it easier to understand:

```
Output (1) of script:
filelocation    =  /home/cas/scripts/
datesetup       =  dd-mm-yyyy
checkdeluge     =  false
showtoken       =  true
standardbackup  =  false
logging         =  true
logfolder       =  /home/cas/scripts/logs/
plexapitoken    =  HfXBs23FhKBGj3msHjAz
ipplexserver    =  192.168.2.15
sonarrapitoken  =  f141c669c71442bf8b87afe9c6c8da17
ipsonarrserver  =  192.168.2.15
sonarrport      =  8005

Output (2) of command from which output 1 is based:
cat "$option"

filelocation="/home/cas/scripts/"
datesetup="dd-mm-yyyy"
checkdeluge="false"
showtoken="true"
standardbackup="false"
logging="true"
logfolder="/home/cas/scripts/logs/"
plexapitoken="HfXBs23FhKBGj3msHjAz"
ipplexserver="192.168.2.15"
sonarrapitoken="f141c669c71442bf8b87afe9c6c8da17"
ipsonarrserver="192.168.2.15"
sonarrport="8005"
```

Now that you have that information, let's come to my question. I want to make a "selection panel" from which the user can select variables and "submit" them. Then, what the user has chosen, should be stored somewhere (e.g. an array). Example:

```
1  | filelocation    =  /home/cas/scripts/
2  | datesetup       =  dd-mm-yyyy
3  | checkdeluge     =  false
4  | showtoken       =  true
5  | standardbackup  =  false
6  | logging         =  true
7  | logfolder       =  /home/cas/scripts/logs/
8  | plexapitoken    =  HfXBs23FhKBGj3msHjAz
9  | ipplexserver    =  192.168.2.15
10 | sonarrapitoken  =  f141c669c71442bf8b87afe9c6c8da17
11 | ipsonarrserver  =  192.168.2.15
12 | sonarrport      =  8005
Choose options: 2|5|12
datesetup       =  dd-mm-yyyy
standardbackup  =  false
sonarrport      =  8005
Do you want to submit these options? (Y|N): Y

-----------------

echo "${selected_options[@]}" -> 2 5 12
```

I could probably make this exactly how I described it above. It's not the hardest thing ever. But the problem is that I think there is a way beter way to "select" those options. Doing "2|5|12" is not... easy. It's not the most user-friendly way of doing it. So I'm asking if there's a beter way of doing this. Is there?

I thought of using a `select` loop, but that didn't work with selecting multiple things. I also thought about the thing that the pi-hole installation does. Kinda like an interface inside the terminal with colors and buttons. Using that, I can do what I want to easily. But I don't want that screen-filling colored interface. [image: Pi-hole interface for installing]

I want to keep it pure-cli.

Comment: This is `whiptail` and afaik, it cannot be used without filling the screen. You could loop `select` and save selections until user chooses `13` -> Done/Quit.

Comment: You gave me an idea. What if I indeed make the user enter a number, let's say 5 and press enter. Then "5" will be shown in a list and you can choose again. Now the user chooses 12, so "12" will be added to the list. And when the user chooses 13, every number in the list will be submited. Kind of like a shopping card. You one-by-one put all the groceries in the card and then go to the cashier. I think that'll be the best solution.